# CompondentDidMount Failed propType- define fetch as a var

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to add CompondentDidMount to my class.

However, this returns the error:

**Failed propType: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `IndexRoute`.**

Here is my attempt to use ComponentDidMount:

```
var PhotoGallery = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount () {
    return fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/test/?format=json")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        this.setState({PHOTODATA: json})
      })
  },
        getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        displayedCategories: []
      };
    },
```

Also, my code works fine if manually set my json data as a var like this:

```
var PHOTODATA = [{ ... *json data* ... }]

    ...

var PhotoGallery = React.createClass({

        getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        displayedCategories: []
      };
    },

    ...

    render: function(){
        var uniqueCategories = PHOTODATA.map(function (photo) {
            return photo.tag; // tag is a list of tags...
        }).reduce(function (uniqueList, someTags) {
            return uniqueList.concat(
              someTags.filter(function (thisTag) {
                return !uniqueList.some(function(uniqueTag) {
                  return uniqueTag.id === thisTag.id && uniqueTag.taglevel === thisTag.taglevel
                });
              })
            );
        }, []
);
```

Full code is in this codepen:

http://codepen.io/yarnball/pen/GqbyWr?

Comment: Can you show us the code of how you are exporting your component `PhotoGallery` and including other components in it, if any?

Comment: Yep- in a codepen http://codepen.io/yarnball/pen/GqbyWr?

Answer (score 0):

In the render function, I used "var PHOTODATA = this.state.PHOTODATA", so I could use it like a var previously.

I also did not define the ComponentDidMount in the far- I instead used "export" like so:

```
export default React.createClass({
  componentWillMount () {
    return fetch("http://localhost:8000/api")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        this.setState({testapi: json})
      })
  },
```

This now worked:

```
render: function(){
    var PHOTODATA = this.state.PHOTODATA
    var uniqueCategories = PHOTODATA.map(function (photo) {
        return photo.tag; // tag is a list of tags...
    }).reduce(function (uniqueList, someTags) {
        return uniqueList.concat(
          someTags.filter(function (thisTag) {
            return !uniqueList.some(function(uniqueTag) {
              return uniqueTag.id === thisTag.id && uniqueTag.taglevel === thisTag.taglevel
            });
          })
        );
    }, 
[]
);
```